# 12 V 6 A power supply for Arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, power

I have 3 motors which work at 12 V 3 A, I have attached a 12 V 6 A power supply and seems to be working fine. However I was wondering if this can also power the Arduino as well.

Comment: As that 3A total for the motors. or 3A per motor? If the latter, then you need a 9A power supply, not 6A.

Comment: @Majenko only if the OP uses all 3 motors at once, if only two are used at a time 6A will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you have 3 motors that use 3Amps combined then you have 3Amps spare and that's more than enough for an Arduino.

I don't understand this part very well but depending on the type of motors you might get noise on the power lines and this might affect you Arduino.  In which case you will need to add in something to smooth the power, which means adding in a capacitor or two and their value depends on the frequency of the noise.  (http://www.valvewizard.co.uk/smoothing.html)

Personally I'd give it a try and see, but there again it wouldn't be the first Arduino I'd fried :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the voltage regulator on the arduino will filter out a lot of this noise.